# How to send private messages in slack channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, slack, slack-api

I am currently sending a message to the slack channel using below function. But I want to send a private message which should be visible to selected member of the slack channel.

How can I do that ?

```
async function sendSlackMessage() {
    const url = 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage';
    const inputBody = {
        channel: "Slack_Channel_ID",
        text: `Hey Welcome to the slack`,
    };

    const slackHeaders = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization': 'Slack_Token',
    };

    const slackRes = await axios.post(url, inputBody, { headers: slackHeaders });
    console.log(slackRes)
}

sendSlackMessage()
```

Comment: The doc's say that you can set a user id as the `channel` property to DM a user.  There are some caveats, though.  See here https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#channels

Answer (score 2):

## **Solution using Boltjs for Javascript:**

To send a private message visible only to a specific user on a channel on Slack, we may use a different method `chat.postEphemeral` from Bolt for JavaScript. Using the above method you can send an ephemeral message to a users in a channel that is visible only to a specific user that you can choose to display.

*Note:* I have offered my solution as simple blocks, you need to encapsulate it within the function you need this feature to operate on.

**Requirements:**
For using the `chat.postEphemeral` you are required to send the following arguments to work.

- ***token**:* Slack_Bot_Token {Authentication token bearing required scopes. Tokens should be passed as an HTTP Authorization header or alternatively, as a POST parameter.}
- ***channel**:* {Channel, private group, or IM channel to send message to. Can be an encoded ID, or a name}
- ***user**:* {id of the user who will receive the ephemeral message. The user should be in the channel specified by the channel argument.}
- ***text**:* "Anything you need here"
- ***blocks**:* "Pack and Send from Block Kit Message Builder, not necessary though"

**Note:**

- extract the channel id from the function or pass it as args to the async function
- extract the user id from the function or pass it as args to the async function
- text field is not enforced when blocks are used.

*Methods Access:* app.client.
chat.postEphemeral

**Required Scopes in Slack App:**

- Bot Tokens
- User Tokens

**Example Code:**

```
// Building the args object from body (Can also use, action, context, and few other slack parameters from Bolt API for js)
  const args = {
    user: body.user.id,
    channel: body.container.channel_id,
    team: body.user.team_id,
    token: body.user.id,
    trigger: body.trigger_id,
    url: body.response_url,
  };
```

**Slack App Code:**

```
 try {
  // Call the chat.postEphemeral method using the WebClient
  const result = await client.chat.postEphemeral({
    channel: channelId,
    user: userId,
    token: userToken,
    text: "Shhhh only you can see this :shushing_face:"
  });

  console.log(result);
}
catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

**Documentation:**

View this documentation for more Information: [Slack API for Methods](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postEphemeral)

Check here to Create Message Block Kits for Slack: [Slack Block Kit Builder](https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/)

Comment: This is awesome to use ephemeral messages but this kind of message doesn't give me a option of reply in thread.

Comment: Okay, if you want to reply to a user in thread, then capture the message.ts or action.ts, user.id and channel.id from the action/body/content of the app. You can use the https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.replies . To know more